# Hyperic HQ add properties to hq-server.conf

Tags: linux, admin, hyperic

Could anyone suggest please how to make Hyperic HQ read custom and overriden properties from *hq-server.conf*? Problem is that when modifying this file Hyperic HQ can't see the changes (I restarted Hyperic HQ after altering *hq-server.conf*). But I guess Hyperic sees the file itself as when i make it blank or commented out Hyperic refuses to start.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in the conf file should be reflected on a restart. Based on the description of the symptoms, I would guess maybe you have a file permission issue. Make sure the conf file is owned by and readable by the user executing Hyperic server.